# Bundle Product - Add to Cart is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, bundle-product

i am facing strange issue.. i have created bundle product with three item.. problem is when i click add to cart, its not working.. i try hard but cant figure out.. where and what is the issue, because there is no java-script error in button add to cart action.. i check code someone suggest this below code in some post.. so i add this code but still not succeed yet.

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

[my bundle product link](http://www.budgetcomputers.biz/amd-6-core-upgrade-bundle.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your add to cart button should look like this:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"> <span> <span><div class="cart-text">Add to Cart</div></span> </span> </button>
```

You should check your `xml` and `phtml` file associated with `add to cart` function.

For bundle product you can start checking on `layout/bundle.xml` and also in `layout/catalog.xml`.

I would suggest to look more specifically in

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

This above block is called from `bundle.xml` file which looks like this:

```
<block type="bundle/catalog_product_view" name="bundle.summary" as="bundleSummary" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml" translate="label">
            <label>Bundle Product View Summary</label>
            <block type="bundle/catalog_product_price" name="bundle.prices" as="bundle_prices" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml">
                <action method="setMAPTemplate"><tmpl>catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml</tmpl></action>
            </block>

            ///// here it is called
            <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
            <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
        </block>
```

I am sure your custom theme is playing the role.

If you still cannot find the solution, then you can try **activating default theme** and see if problem actually with your theme.

Good luck.